# Controller action enum parameter binding as string

Tags: json, enums, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API controller action

```
[Route("{type}")]
public IEnumerable<Content> Get(ContentType type)
{
    ...
}
```

where `ContentType` is enumeration and `type` is being provided as a string and not as an integer.

As I've checked the `JsonConverterAttribute` class which seems it should be possible to put it beside a method parameter

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class |
                AttributeTargets.Struct |
                AttributeTargets.Enum |
                AttributeTargets.Property |
                AttributeTargets.Field |
                AttributeTargets.Interface |
                AttributeTargets.Parameter, // <= HERE!
                AllowMultiple = false)]
public class JsonConverterAttribute : Attribute
...
```

but this doesn't seem to work:

```
[Route("{type}")]
public IEnumerable<Content> Get([JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] ContentType type)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'type' of non-nullable type '....ContentType' for method '...' in '...'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

I also don't want to put this converter inside my global configuration as I want my enums to serialize as integers. There are just a few places where I need to **deserialize** them from strings.

The possible alternative is to pass in a string and parse it manually using `Enum.Parse()` method but I'd like to avoid it if possible.